# Can you extract the blobs from an OTM ROM?

Tags: android, blob, lineageos

I didn't find any other place to put this, so I put it here. I finally got a successful lineage build this morning (surnia), and I am now trying to build for athene (Moto G4/ G4 Plus), which is discontinued. Because of that, I have no place to get the blobs since it isn't in TheMuppets library either. I do have a Moto G4 Plus with the Stock ROM installed though. So can I extract the blobs from there, or is there another way to get the blobs? I can get them from older builds, but prefer not to.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my manifest here. Haven't been much active, but should be fine:

[LocalManifest](https://github.com/rajatgupta1998/local_manifests/tree/lineage-15.1)